# How to detect timeouts in an expect script

Tags: automation, expect, automated-testing

Consider an expect script that spawns a command and waits for a sequence of events. We use this to test software. I'm trying to always get a failure return value from the script when there is a timeout.

```
spawn some-command

set timeout 10

expect "First message"
expect "Other message"
```

This script will always return 0 (success) even when the timeout hits. The only way to handle timeouts is to convert every expect statement with:

```
expect {
    timeout { exit 1 }
    eof     { exit 1 }
    "First message"
}
```

But this quickly becomes unwieldy. Are there any simplifications? Is there an expect option that makes early timeout / eof fatal errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commenting on [meuh's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/981699/30957), `expect_before` takes the same arguments as `expect`, so you can write it like this:

```
expect_before {
    timeout { puts "timeout"; exit 2 }
    eof     { puts "eof";     exit 1 }
}
# ...
expect "First message"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can setup an `expect_before` command. This will be run every time you use `expect` later in the script. Eg

```
proc abort { } { send_user "Timeout!" ; exit 2 }
set timeout 5
spawn ssh myhost
expect_before timeout abort
expect  "assword: "
send "abc\r"
expect  "$ "
send "sleep 99\r"
expect  "$ "
```